# how to get multiple checkbox value in "KOHANA FRAMEWORK"?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

"KOHANA FRAMEWORK" submit button how to get selected check box value and how to insert in database.
My page has two fields textbox and second checkbox.
I trying to insert checkbox and textbox value but textbox value is possible to get but checkbox value is not.

=====> add.php

```
<?php echo form::open('backend/notifications/add/', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) ?>

<div class="staffWrapper">

          <h2 style="float: left;">List Companies</h2>
          <div class="clear"></div>



          <table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed;" border="0">
              <tr>
                  <th width="20"><input type='checkbox' id='selectall' style='width:15px;'/></th>
                  <th width="210">Name</th>
                  <th width="100">Contact Person</th>
                  <th width="100">Phone</th>
                  <th width="210">Email</th>
                  <!-- <th width="80" colspan="2">Actions</th> -->
              </tr>

              <?php
              if (count($companies)) {
                  $i = (isset($_GET['page']) ? ($_GET['page']-1)*50+1 : 1);
                  foreach ($companies as $company) {    

                      echo $i % 2 ? '<tr class="even">' : '<tr class="odd">';
                      // echo "<td align='center'>" . $i . "</td>";
                      echo "<td align='center'>";
                      echo '<input type="checkbox" id="PILIH" name="PILIH[]" class="PILIH" value='.$company['id'].' style="width:15px;"/>';
                      echo "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $company['name'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $company['contact_person'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $company['phone'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $company['email'] . "</td>";
                      $i++;
                  }
              } else if (empty ($companies) && $searchKey){
                   echo '<tr class="odd">';
                   echo '<td colspan="7" align="center"><h3>No mathcing results were found for this search term.</h3></td>';
                   echo '</tr>';
              } else if (empty ($companies)){    
                  echo '<tr class="odd">';
                  echo '<td colspan="7" align="center"><h3>There are no companies.</h3></td>';
                  echo '</tr>';
              }
              ?>
          </table>

         <?php echo $pagination; ?> 
      </div>

 <div class="clear"></div>

    <div style="float:right; margin-right: 335px; padding:10px 0 10px 0;">
        <?php echo form::submit('', 'Create Notifications', array('class' => 'submit')) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php echo form::close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same way as in pure PHP.

```
$PILIH = !empty($_POST['PILIH'])?$_POST['PILIH']:Array(); // pure PHP
$PILIH = Array::get($_POST, 'PILIH', Array());
$PILIH = $this->request->post('PILIH', Array()); //Where $this is Controller
$PILIH = Request::current()->post('PILIH', Array());
```

As a result, you will get an array from company-ID or an empty array, so:

```
$company_id = NULL; 
$q = DB::query(Databse::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO foo (company_id) VALUES (:company_id)')->bind(':company_id', $company_id);
foreach($PILIH AS $company_id) {
   $q->execute(); 
}
```

You did not give too much input, so: happy code analysis. [And](http://v2docs.kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/query/builder#insert): [RTFM](http://v2docs.kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/examples/validation).